# Как в переменную status поместить следующую строку user_name user_family is position

Tags: python

```
status = user_name' + + 'user_family' + is + 'position
```

Ответ приходит name status is not defined

Comment: Тут вообще какая-то синтаксически некорректная чепуха написана, ничего не понятно, нужен [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

```py
>>> user_name = 'Вася'
>>> user_family = 'Пупкин'
>>> position = 'death'
>>> status = user_name + ' ' + user_family + ' is ' + position
>>> status
'Вася Пупкин is death'
```

но выхлоп можно(и даже лучше) так:

```py
>>> status = f'{user_name} {user_family} is {position}'
>>> status
'Вася Пупкин is death'
```